# Join large table with small table in postgres with index

Tags: postgresql, join, indexing

We have a database that consists of 96 million mortgage loans. In this database we have the original houseprice at loan origination. We want to update these houseprices with a very simple houseprice index we extracted from the internet as csv and I imported this to a table in the same database as the mortgage loans. I am already able to join the tables, but it is very slow. I think I'm not working with the index correctly.... This is how the tables look like:
mortgage loans:

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.mortgageloans
(
  pkrmbloan bigint NOT NULL,
  fkdeal bigint NOT NULL,
  edcode character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  poolcutoffdate character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  recno integer NOT NULL,
  submissiontimestamp timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  col1 character varying(10),
  col2 character varying(100),
  country character varying(10),
  col......
  col199 character varying(25)
CONSTRAINT rmb_loan_pkey PRIMARY KEY (pkrmbloan),
  CONSTRAINT fk_rmbloan2deal FOREIGN KEY (fkdeal)
      REFERENCES mydb_data.deal (pkdeal) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE mydb.mortgageloans
  OWNER TO mydb_admin;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE mydb.mortgageloans TO mydb_admin;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE mydb.mortgageloans TO mydb_addon;

CREATE INDEX idx_rmbloan_edcode_poolcod
  ON mydb.mortgageloans
  USING btree
  (edcode COLLATE pg_catalog."default", poolcutoffdate COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE INDEX idx_rmbloan_fkdeal
  ON mydb.mortgageloans
  USING btree
  (fkdeal);

CREATE INDEX idx_rmbloan_recno
  ON mydb.mortgageloans
  USING btree
  (recno);
```

house price index table I self imported.

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.hpi
(
  period character varying(100),
  au character varying(100),
  be character varying(100),
  ca character varying(100),
  ch character varying(100),
  de character varying(100),
  dk character varying(100),
  es character varying(100),
  fi character varying(100),
  fr character varying(100),
  uk character varying(100),
  ie character varying(100),
  it character varying(100),
  jp character varying(100),
  nl character varying(100),
  no character varying(100),
  nz character varying(100),
  us character varying(100),
  pt character varying(100)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE mydb.hpi
  OWNER TO mydb_admin;
```

And the query to add the original house price index based on the loan origination date (col55)

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.mortgageloans ADD COLUMN OriginalHPI varchar(130);
UPDATE mydb.mortgageloans set OriginalHPI = test.rv
FROM
(
select 
CASE
            WHEN a.country = 'NL'::text THEN c.nl::numeric
            WHEN a.country = 'BE'::text THEN c.be::numeric
            WHEN a.country = 'ES'::text THEN c.es::numeric
            WHEN a.country = 'FR'::text THEN c.fr::numeric
            WHEN a.country = 'IT'::text THEN c.IT::numeric
            WHEN a.country = 'DE'::text THEN c.de::numeric
            WHEN a.country = 'IE'::text THEN c.ie::numeric
            else NULL::numeric
            END AS rv,
 ,a.pkrmbloan
FROM mydb.mortgageloans a
LEFT JOIN mydb_data.hpi c on a.col55 = c.Period
)
 as test
 where test.pkrmbloan = mydb.mortgageloans.pkrmbloan
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Best regards,

Tim

edit: added the explain output

- Using slightly different db names, wanted to anonomize first

Actual query:

```
EXPLAIN
UPDATE edp_data.rmb_loan set OriginalHPI = test.rv
FROM
(
select 
CASE
            WHEN "substring"(a.edcode::text, 5, 2)::text = 'NL'::text THEN c.nl::numeric
            WHEN "substring"(a.edcode::text, 5, 2)::text = 'BE'::text THEN c.be::numeric
            WHEN "substring"(a.edcode::text, 5, 2)::text = 'ES'::text THEN c.es::numeric
            WHEN "substring"(a.edcode::text, 5, 2)::text = 'FR'::text THEN c.fr::numeric
            WHEN "substring"(a.edcode::text, 5, 2)::text = 'IT'::text THEN c.IT::numeric
            WHEN "substring"(a.edcode::text, 5, 2)::text = 'DE'::text THEN c.de::numeric
            WHEN "substring"(a.edcode::text, 5, 2)::text = 'IE'::text THEN c.ie::numeric
            else 12::numeric
            END AS rv,
 a.pkrmbloan, a.fkdeal
FROM edp_data.rmb_loan a
LEFT JOIN edp_data.hpi c on a.ar55 = c.period
)
 as test
 where test.pkrmbloan = edp_data.rmb_loan.pkrmbloan and test.fkdeal = edp_data.rmb_loan.fkdeal;
```

Output

```
"Update on rmb_loan  (cost=22.11..60667621.09 rows=342266 width=4090)"
"  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=22.11..60667621.09 rows=342266 width=4090)"
"        Hash Cond: ((a.ar55)::text = (c.period)::text)"
"        ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.00..60635941.00 rows=341941 width=4049)"
"              Merge Cond: (rmb_loan.pkrmbloan = a.pkrmbloan)"
"              Join Filter: (rmb_loan.fkdeal = a.fkdeal)"
"              ->  Index Scan using rmb_loan_pkey on rmb_loan  (cost=0.00..28746023.33 rows=179651105 width=4014)"
"              ->  Index Scan using rmb_loan_pkey on rmb_loan a  (cost=0.00..28746023.33 rows=179651105 width=51)"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=15.38..15.38 rows=538 width=56)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on hpi c  (cost=0.00..15.38 rows=538 width=56)"
```

Comment: Please update the question with the `EXPLAIN` output for the query.

Comment: I don't see why mydb.mortgageloans needs to be in that query twice, it is just joined to itself on a primary key.  Can you expand the EXPLAIN to be `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your confusing `from` clause originates from the fact that you want the column default to be `12`. To avoid that just declare the default when adding the column

```
alter table mydb.mortgageloans
add column OriginalHPI varchar(130) default '12';

update edp_data.rmb_loan a
set OriginalHPI = (
    case substring(a.edcode::text, 5, 2)
        when 'NL' then c.nl
        when 'BE' then c.be
        when 'ES' then c.es
        when 'FR' then c.fr
        when 'IT' then c.IT
        when 'DE' then c.de
        when 'IE' then c.ie
        else 12
    end)::numeric
from edp_data.hpi c
where a.ar55 = c.period
```

Why do you cast the `case` result to `numeric` just to save it in a `varchar` column?

Comment: All the columns are varchar in the DB (from another company), so I thought I needed to save it as varchar as well. Now I see that doesn't make sense. thanks. We have a primarykey on the table mortgageloans, can I try something with that to increase speed? It now takes 9 hours for 96 million rows... But maybe this is just what you get with so many rows and a join. Thanks!